Login page isn't redirecting using oath2/oidc
Im trying to implement spring security using oauth2 and oidc provider in my spring mvc non boot application.
EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:
When the user access to a secured endpoint, he will be redirected to the automatic login page ( combining all the parameters ( client_id + secret_id + ....))
ACTUAL BEHAVIOUR:
when the user access to a secured endpoint , nothing is done
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                    .antMatchers("/page").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(XClientRegistration());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
        return new AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientService());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService() {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository());
    }

    private ClientRegistration XClientRegistration() {
        logger.debug("Configuring x Client Registration");
        return ClientRegistrations
                .fromIssuerLocation("https://CONF.com/")
                .clientId("xxxx")
                .clientSecret("xxxx")
                .scope("openid")
                .redirectUri("/OAUTH2").build();
    }

}

i tried this configuration , but i tried implementing it directly in the controller but its not what i want i want the login page redirection to be automatich which is actually the point of spring security

.antMatchers("/page").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll() => you allow anonymous requests to everything but /page => redirection will happen only when an anonymous request targets /page
As a side note, disabling protection against CSRF on a client with oauth2Login is very unsafe: requests are authorized with sessions (not Bearer tokens), which are the vector for CSRF attacks.

even when i specified only .antMatchers("/page").authenticated() i still have the problem;

If you jhad joined the DEBUG log, we'd have more info about this error. Maybe we'd know if you have the same error or a different one when you exclude .anyRequest().permitAll() {in this second case you might have an error because the redirectUri is not accessible anymore)
